# Outlook not receiving mails from Laravel hosted website

Tags: php, email, laravel-5

I have implemented a mailing system in Laravel which send mails to the users. When tried from localhost, it is sending emails to both Gmail and outlook, but when I moved the code to production only Gmail accounts are receiving the mails.

**.env**

```
MAIL_DRIVER="smtp" 
MAIL_HOST="smtp.gmail.com" 
MAIL_PORT="587"
MAIL_ENCRYPTION="tls"
```

Comment: When you say "Outlook" what do you mean? That platform has a lot of different meanings over the years from `outlook.office.com` to a thick client that can be on top of Exchange and non-Exchange backends. Does your sending server get an email back from the server that rejected your mail with an error?

Comment: Have you checked the spam folder? Different clients/email providers can have different rules/services for detecting/flagging emails as spam.

Comment: Check with your hosting provider first, many would block smtp by default to avoid spam or using a different port.

Comment: @JNevill yes outlook.office.com .. yes the i have checked the outbox of the server's email that the email has been sent

Comment: @M.Eriksson yes i have checked the spam email is not recieved